# Alkaline cooking

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, alkalinity

I have a (molecular) cooking recipe with instructions on introducing an agent to create an alkaline (base) environment while cooking (to influence the Maillard reaction).

What 'normal'/common ingredients can I use to create such an environment in my pan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is absolutely correct, an alkaline environment will speed Maillard reactions, and baking soda is a simple choice for creating it. The one thing to watch out for, depending on what you are cooking is that it can also create a mushy texture. You'll want to use a very small amount, less than 1% by weight for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Baking soda is the easiest and safest way to get a base in cooking. I've never heard of using it for browning, though.

Comment: Lowering the PH aids browning. A lot of pretzel recipes will have a baking soda wash for this purpose (as well as texture).

Comment: @Sobachatina: Lower pH = more acidic.  A base (higher alkalinity) would have a higher pH.

Comment: @Sobachatina Now that I think about it, I think I have seen pretzel and bagel recipes that used either baking soda or a lye solution . . . but I certainly wouldn't recommend anyone use lye in a home kitchen.

Comment: Here's a chicken recipe that uses baking powder to get a nice crisp brown skin -- I guess because of the influence on the Maillard reaction: http://thepauperedchef.com/2008/02/crisp-skinned-r.html

Comment: @Martha baking powder actually contains baking soda (base) + cream of tartar (acid), leaving it with a neutral (or close to it) ph. I wonder why that recipe works; it seems that straight baking soda would do a better job.